# xamarin android AddToBackStack(typeof(MainActivity).Name) does not working

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

please help me to solve this problem
Hello dear friends .
I'm developing an app. I do not know why the command does not work back to the previous screen in the app.
Exit the app by pressing the **Back button**.
The app is running added data to `fragment manager` backstack.

```
namespace SakhtemanYar
{
    public class MainFragment : Fragment, Com.Mohamadamin.Persianmaterialdatetimepicker.Date.DatePickerDialog.IOnDateSetListener
    {
        // Global variables

    public MainFragment(Context context, int pageid, Account myaccount, ConnectivityManager conn, List<Setting> appstgs, object transaction = null, string objecttype = "")
    {
        PageID = pageid;
        // main startup operations
        string path = "BKoodkBd.ttf";
        FontTypeface = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(context.Assets, path);

    }
    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view;

        if (PageID == 0)
        {
            view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.HomePage, container, false);
    ...
    ...
            SeewIV.Click += delegate
            {
                SetLayoutPage(15, true);
            };
        }

        else
            view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.HomePage, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    public void SetLayoutPage(int pageid, bool rollback = false, object transobject = null, string objecttype = "")
    {
        if (transobject == null && objecttype == "")
        {
            var newFragment = new MainFragment(Context, pageid, MyAccountFr, connectivityManager, AppSettings);
            var ft = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            ft.Replace(Resource.Id.MainFrame, newFragment);

            if (rollback)
                ft.AddToBackStack(typeof(MainActivity).Name);

            ft.Commit();
        }
        else
        {
            var newFragment = new MainFragment(Context, pageid, MyAccountFr, connectivityManager, AppSettings, transobject, objecttype);
            var ft = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            ft.Replace(Resource.Id.MainFrame, newFragment);

            if (rollback)
                ft.AddToBackStack(typeof(MainActivity).Name);

            ft.Commit();
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: It would be worth creating a sample project with this code that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Please show where you add the `MainFragment` in your activity.

Comment: hi . i dont understand your comment.

Comment: In your `MainFragment` layout, there is a button and when you click it, your `MainFragment` will replace `MainFrame` which is also in your `MainFragment` layout, these are what I read from your code, but the fragment is based on Activity, and you haven't show the code in your activity where you add the `MainFragment`.

Comment: Could you please push a demo to reproduce your problem?

Comment: http://s8.picofile.com/file/8315930492/MainActivity.cs.html

Comment: http://s9.picofile.com/file/8315930550/MainFragment.cs.html

Comment: I am not mean your origin code, it is too complex, I mean a simple which can reproduce the problem.

Comment: i solved him self .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public class MainFragment : Fragment

= >

public class MainFragment : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment